# What is the best way to create a database connection between flutter and native (android and ios) without a backend server?

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, kotlin

I am trying to create a project that in background if app terminated fetched data on (ios and android), without to create a external backend api server, and flutter can get this data after it is opened, and opposite native get data from flutter, after saving data in the database.

Anyone has an idea about what should I use to do this, or to create a database communication between flutter and native (ios and android)?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

it can be done simple steps

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

// Create your storage
final mystorage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read your values 
String value = await mystorage.read(key: key);

// Read all values
Map<String, String> allValues = await mystorage.readAll();

// Delete value 
await mystorage.delete(key: key);

// Delete all 
await mystorage.deleteAll();

// Write value 
await mystorage.write(key: key, value: value);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but my problem is, I dont know how can I access to the saved data from native code (swift or kotlin)

Comment: you dont need to add it to native code just import library it compatible to android and ios

Comment: I know, to complete my project, i should pragramming in native and access to saved data

Comment: you have to pass data true library

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Background Fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) which might help you. It wakes up the app in the background about every 15 minutes and runs a callback. You could use the callback to fetch data from a remote database and store it in a SQLite database or as data files on the user's device. The data will be available on the device when the user reopens the app. If you need to fetch a large amount of data, maybe you should fetch the data in small batches with a flag to keep track of the last chunk of data fetched.